# How to initialize AWS SDK in spring boot application?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am writing a spring boot application which reads messages from SQS. I am able to run the application using environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. However, I was wondering it would be simpler to pass this configuration via a file similar to `application.properties`.  How to achieve this?

Comment: Where is your application running: in AWS on EC2 or outside AWS?

Comment: I need to manage both cases. For development, it runs on my mac, and in production it will run on EC2.

Answer (score 17):

In spring boot application you can access properties mentioned in `application.yml` file with `@value` annotation. You can create a service like this:

```
@Service
public class AmazonClient {  
    private AmazonSQS sqsClient;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initializeAmazon() {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
        this.sqsClient = AmazonSQSClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .build();

    }
}
```

In `application.yml` file:

```
amazonProperties:
   accessKey: <your_access_key>
   secretKey: <your_secret_key>
```

Answer (score 9):

Change for aws sdk 2.0 is as follows..

```
    AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);

    S3Client client = S3Client.builder().region(Region.AP_SOUTH_1)
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 8):

If you utilise spring cloud AWS with spring boot, some AWS clients (like SQS and SNS) and EC2 meta data can be setup for you via auto-configuration. For local testing you can use static providers set via application properties.

Documentation: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-aws.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration

Specifically, you can set properties such as `cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey` and `cloud.aws.region.static`.

Answer (score 4):

I avoid using property file, rather use Credential Provider Chain more here, [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)

Although, property file can also be overridden by environment variable, but If I always need to do so, why should I even mention it in property file. 
Also I would also like to avoid from committing keys in code ( in properties file)

Moreover, when I look at my CI/CD , it makes sense and also easy to just set environment variable for your Spring Boot Environment - specially on cloud. If using docker env, even more easier and much more cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running your service in EC2(mostly non-development environments) then there is no need for configuring the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, because of `EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper` the credentials will be automatically fetched from the AWS container.

```
    @Profile({"non-prod", "prod"})
    @Bean("AWSCredentialsProvider")
    public AWSCredentialsProvider amazonAWSCredentialsProvider() {
        return new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper();
    }
```

NOTE: If you decided to use any of below mentioned `AWSCredentialsProviderChain` then use `AWSCredentialsProvider` and not `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` otherwise you will endup with 
`com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The security token included in the request is expired` exception.

- DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
- EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider
- SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider
- ProfileCredentialsProvider
- EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper

If the application running outside the AWS then you can use `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` with hard coded values of `awsAccessKeyId` and `awsSecretAccessKey`

```
aws.awsAccessKeyId:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws.awsSecretAccessKey:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

```
    @Value("${aws.awsAccessKeyId:}")
    private String awsAccessKeyId;

    @Value("${aws.awsSecretAccessKey:}")
    private String awsSecretAccessKey;

    @Profile({"dev", "test"})
    @Bean("AWSCredentialsProvider")
    public AWSStaticCredentialsProvider amazonAWSCredentialsProviderDevelopment() {
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways you can manage it.

1. You can configure aws configure (on your local or Linux machine)  which will be required your secret key and access key then you don't need to pass these in api by default constructor you can create connection as it will pick secret key, etc from system path.

   ```
   AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient();
   ```

[How to configure aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

2. If you are using AWS EC2 then when you create ec2 instance, make sure assign it a role which has permission to SQS then you don't need to even configure on that machine.
3. You can define your ACCESS KEY AND SECRET KEY in `application/properties` and load in sqs class by `@Value`.
4. You can create `aws.keys` in your `classpath` and can load properties from a file.
5. Of course you can define them as constant in your `Constant class`.