# Error during AWS connection using S3Client Java spring 'Expected an '=' sign defining a property

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use S3Client to initiate a connection to a S3 bucket hosted on a cloud provider to get and upload documents.

I have a java spring boot application and I'm using the following versions:

- Java: 17
- Spring: 3.0.7
- software.amazon.awssdk: 2.20.127

I implemented the following service:

```
imports...

public class ScalewayStorageService {

    private final String SCALEWAY_ENDPOINT_URL = "xx";

    private final String SCALEWAY_REGION = "fr-par";

    private final String SCALEWAY_BUCKET_NAME = "xx";


    private final S3Client client;


    public ScalewayStorageService(final String accessKey, final String secretKey) {
        this.client = S3Client.builder().region(Region.of(SCALEWAY_REGION))
                .endpointOverride(URI.create(SCALEWAY_ENDPOINT_URL))
                .credentialsProvider(
                        StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
                                AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey)))
                .build();
    }

    public ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> download(final String path) {
        final GetObjectRequest objectRequest =
                GetObjectRequest
                        .builder()
                        .key(path)
                        .bucket(SCALEWAY_BUCKET_NAME)
                        .build();

        return client.getObject(objectRequest);
    }

    protected void shutdown() {
        this.client.close();
    }

}
```

Then I have this GetMapping in a ressource:

```
   @GetMapping("/object-storage")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getDocument() {
        log.debug("REST request to get Document from object storage");
        ScalewayStorageService scalewayStorageService = new ScalewayStorageService(accessKey, secretKey);
        ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> responseResponseInputStream = scalewayStorageService.download(imagepath);
        log.debug("responseResponseInputStream : {}", responseResponseInputStream);
        return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of("Test"));
    }
```

And I get the following error:

```
2023-08-20T20:34:46.690+02:00 ERROR 7721 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] c.s.app.web.rest.ObjectStorageResource   : Exception in getDocument() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'Expected an '=' sign defining a property on line 12' 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected an '=' sign defining a property on line 12
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:76)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.internal.ProfileFileReader.parsePropertyDefinition(ProfileFileReader.java:243)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.internal.ProfileFileReader.readPropertyContinuationLine(ProfileFileReader.java:173)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.internal.ProfileFileReader.parseLine(ProfileFileReader.java:81)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.internal.ProfileFileReader.lambda$parseFile$0(ProfileFileReader.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.internal.ProfileFileReader.parseFile(ProfileFileReader.java:59)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.ProfileFile$BuilderImpl.build(ProfileFile.java:309)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.ProfileFile.lambda$addConfigFile$1(ProfileFile.java:160)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.ProfileFile.addConfigFile(ProfileFile.java:157)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.builder.SdkBuilder.applyMutation(SdkBuilder.java:61)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.ProfileFile.defaultProfileFile(ProfileFile.java:99)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.lambda$mergeGlobalDefaults$2(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:267)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.mergeGlobalDefaults(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:267)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.syncClientConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:177)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3ClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultS3ClientBuilder.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3ClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultS3ClientBuilder.java:29)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.build(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:147)
    at com.social420cloud.app.service.ScalewayStorageService.<init>(ScalewayStorageService.java:32)
    at com.social420cloud.app.web.rest.ObjectStorageResource.getDocument(ObjectStorageResource.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at com.social420cloud.app.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:105)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:637)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:71)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)
    at com.social420cloud.app.web.rest.ObjectStorageResource$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getDocument(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:399)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:297)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at com.social420cloud.app.web.filter.SpaWebFilter.doFilterInternal(SpaWebFilter.java:30)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:280)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

2023-08-20T20:34:46.695+02:00 ERROR 7721 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] c.s.app.web.rest.ObjectStorageResource   : Illegal argument: [] in getDocument()
```

Any ideas how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you using a `~/.aws/config` file to supply AWS credentials? Is it valid (at line 12)?

Comment: Hello @jarmod, I’m using credentials provided by my cloud provider accessKey, secretKey, line 12 is in some Java file ( it part of my project)

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading this, but the stack trace appears to show the error happens during the AWS SDK's reading of a configuration profile.

Comment: I'm using         var credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create("xxx", "xxx"); to privide credentials @jarmod, using  software.amazon.awssdk, I may not need .aws/config no?

Comment: And no, i'm not using any ~/.aws/config so I don't know where this line 12 is referenced

Comment: The underlying code seems to be attempting to read an AWS config or credentials file. You can see that in the stack trace - the reference to [ProfileFileReader](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/profiles/internal/ProfileFileReader.html). That's typically `~/.aws/config` or whatever the environment variable `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` points to. Do you use that env var, or do you actually have a `~/.aws/` folder with files in it?

Comment: Can you pinpoint the code at line number `com.social420cloud.app.service.ScalewayStorageService.<init>(ScalewayStorageService.java:32)` and `com.social420cloud.app.web.rest.ObjectStorageResource.getDocument(ObjectStorageResource.java:35)`

Comment: Can you specify where this code is hosted? If aws then which service you are using ECS, EC2 etc?

Comment: Try deleting "~/.aws" folder and rerun the code. I tried running your code using my access and secret key and found it to be working.

Comment: If you are trying to access S3 from EC2/ECS, please don't use StaticCredentialsProvider for resource authentication, please follow the answer to use the proper AWS authentication https://stackoverflow.com/a/59781080/3303074

Answer (score 4):

The problem (as some Commentators have said) is that the fault occurs when the AWS client is being built and it parses a file that is somehow corrupt.

The normal behaviour, *even if you provide static credentials*, is for the Default Client to *merge* in settings that you may have set in the global files.  The are two files AWS expects - a configuration file (this is used, for example, to provide a default Region) and a credentials file.

The global files are located in well-known locations (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html) which are very likely to be in the home directory of the user process called `.aws/credentials` and `.aws/config`.

The stack trace shows that the problem is the `.aws/config` file... and you must have some invalid syntax in the file.

I was able to reproduce the problem exactly you had shown simply by editing this file to have a file like this:

```
[default]
X
```

The problem is line 2 which is expected to be of the form `X=Y`

(Although in your case the fault is on line 12.)

So to fix the problem you have two options.

1. Track down that file and alter line 12 to make it parseable by the AWS client.  (Or delete the file)
2. Provide a code workaround

If you cannot locate the file, don't have access to it, or the file is somehow injected, etc, then the following code will alter the Default Client's behaviour to look elsewhere for another file.  The only caveat is that this must be a readable file, but it can be entirely empty.  So I created an empty file at this location `/tmp/empty`, obviously you could make a file where ever possible, and then add the following lines to your code:

```
public Main(final String accessKey, final String secretKey) {
    this.client = S3Client.builder().region(Region.of(SCALEWAY_REGION))
            
            // workaround to misdirect AWS to avoid looking in the normal place for its configuration file
            // ------------
            .overrideConfiguration(
                    ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                            .defaultProfileFile(ProfileFile.builder()
                                    .content(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/tmp", "empty"))
                                    .type(ProfileFile.Type.CONFIGURATION)
                                    .build())
                            .build()
            )
            // ------------
            .endpointOverride(URI.create(SCALEWAY_ENDPOINT_URL))
            .credentialsProvider(
                    StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
                            AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey)))
            .build();
}
```